# How can I connect to postgres data base by input parameters?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database by using psycopg2. I ask for the user and user password via input. But I think, this way doesnt let me connect to the database. Is there another way to place the values?

I try to connect like this:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=%s password=%s", (username, password))
```

This is the error I get:

```
    connection = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you want to use %-replacement? In that case you are just missing a % sign where you placed a comma between your template-string and the tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to build the connection string from inputs, first:

```
# From input
user_name = 'some_name'
pwd = 'some_pwd'

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=localhost, dbname=dbname, user=user_name, password=pwd)
```

Second from here [Make dsn](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html?highlight=make_dsn#psycopg2.extensions.make_dsn):

```
from psycopg2.extensions import make_dsn
dsn = make_dsn('host=localhost dbname=dbname', user=user_name, password=pwd)
connection = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
```

**UPDATE**, forgot the most obvious way:

```
dsn = 'host=localhost dbname=dbname user=' + user_name + ' password='  + pwd
connection = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
```